# If deadLetterQueue is encrypted shouldn't lambda know how to decrypt master key?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-cdk

As in question. Wonder about use case where deadLetterQueue passed to lambda function is actually encrypted. Shouldn't a policy in lambda include permissions to decrypt `sqs.IQueue` `encryptionMasterKey`? Similarly to what `grantConsumeMessages` is doing?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you having an issue with lambda?

Comment: No, not having. Just theorizing :)

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: If lambda is configured with DLQ that is encrypted does lambda need permission to access a key DLQ is configured with or does that happens before message reaches lambda i.e. lambda failed to process message thus it lands in DLQ.